# Apache Virtual Host on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have been trying to setup virtual host on apache2. Most of the answers I have seen have been including steps which include uncommenting the include line in httpd.conf, but my httpd.conf file is empty. I installed my apache by using "sudo apt-get install apache2".

Answer (score 2):

Apache Virtualhost configurations in Debian, and as an extension Ubuntu, are stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder. The debian tools used for managing them are `a2ensite` and `a2dissite`.

These create and delete symlinks for vhost entries in `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`.

If you'd see your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, the virtualhost entries are included in the very last line:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```